# How does one pump text into a scrolling window in streamlit?

Tags: streamlit

I have seen streamlit display scrolling text windows. In particular, they get displayed for dataframes.

Is there a way to somehow write incrementally to a, **for example** scrolling `info`, `warning` and `error` text window with the same color codes as the `info`, `warning` and `error` text lines written to the screen with `streamlit.info("foo"), streamlit.warning("bar"), && streamlit.error("foobar")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by a scrolling text window, but using the `st.empty()`, you can continuously write over the same object, which gives the effect of what I think you're asking for:

```py
import streamlit as st
import time

c = st.empty()

for i in range(1, 30):
    time.sleep(0.5) #just here so you can see the change
    c.text(i)
```

This example can be extended to anything where you can consistently append/pop data off a list, indexing, etc.

Edit: note that what I'm referring to as `c` here ends up being the generic Streamlit class that contains most/all of the widgets. So `text` could be swapped out for `dataframe`, `metric` and any number of other Streamlit widgets.